# Removing tab space from text box in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, javascript-objects

How can I remove tab space value from a text box. My functional code is::

```
function validTitle() {
if (window.document.all.dDocTitle.value == "") {
alert("Please enter the Title");
window.document.all.dDocTitle.focus();
return false;
} 
return true;
}
```

I want to add 1 more condition for removing tab space in text box for value captured with window.document.all.dDocTitle.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [String.trim()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) function () :

```
function validTitle() {
  // just a remark: use document.getElementById('textbox_id') instead, it's more supported
  var textBox = window.document.all.dDocTitle; 
  if (!(typeof textBox.value  === 'string') || !textBox.value.trim()) { // if textbox contains only whitespaces
    alert("Please enter the Title");
    textBox.focus();
    return false;
  } 

  // remove all tab spaces in the text box
  textBox.value = textBox.value.replace(/\t+/g,'');

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i did it but it still didn't give the alert in case of trim. For testing, i copy pasted a tab space title from a notepad to the title field but it does not give the alert. In short, i want to restrict users from entering tab space title from any source as it creates a problem when this metadata flows in third application

Comment: I did this and it is also not working.........                                                 function validTitle() {
    if (window.document.all.dDocTitle.value == "")  {
       alert("Please enter the Title");
       window.document.all.dDocTitle.focus();
       return false;
    }
   window.document.all.dDocTitle.value =value.replace(/(^[\t]+|[\t]+$)/g,''); 
    return true;
 }

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstood your need. I just edited my solution. I think this is what you need.

Comment: If you need to remove tab spaces from the beginning and the end of your text box, the trim function do it : textBox.value = textBox.value.trim();

Comment: Thanks @Nabil Semaoune . you hit the bulls eye. really appreciate it.